# Data driven navigation in grails and gsp

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a Section domain object which looks like this :-

```
    class Section {
        String name;
        Section parent;
        int level = 0;
        Boolean isRoot = false;
        static hasMany = [children:Section]
        static mappedBy = [children:'parent']
        ....
        def Boolean isLeaf(){
            return children.isEmpty()
        }
    }
```

And a Story domain object that look this : -

```
class Story {
   String title;
   String story;
   List link;
   List substory;
   List picture;
   Section publishUnder
   ....
}
```

In Bootsrap.groovy I set the sections up like this :-

```
    def Section Home = new Section(name:"Home").save(flush: true);
    def Section News = new Section(name:"News").save(flush: true);
        def Section News_Crime = new Section(name:"Crime",parent:News).save(flush: true);
        def Section News_Politics = new Section(name:"Politics",parent:News).save(flush: true);
           def Section News_Politics_Labour = new Section(name:"Labour",parent:News_Politics).save(flush: true);
           def Section News_Politics_Tories = new Section(name:"Tories",parent:News_Politics).save(flush: true);
           def Section News_Politics_LibDems = new Section(name:"LibDems",parent:News_Politics).save(flush: true);
```

Stories are published under Sections. I then have a Section service that looks like this :-

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Section[] getSectionsForCurrentPage(Long sectionID = 0)
    {
    def rootLevel = 0
    def Section selectedSection = Section.get(sectionID)?:Section.findByName("Home")
    def Section[] sectionList = []
    (sectionList as List).add(0,[sectionInstanceList: Section.findWhere(level:rootLevel)])  
    if(!selectedSection.isLeaf()){
            sectionList[1] = [sectionInstanceList:Section.findWhere(level:1,parent:selectedSection)]//just for testing needs to be iterative
    }

}
```

The GSP template looks like this:-

```
<%@ page import="com.keane.reg.content.Section" %>

<header>
<g:each in = "${sectionList}" status="i" var = "sectionInstanceList">
    <div id="navLevel_+${i}}" class="headerNav">        
    <ul class="navLevel_+${i}}">            
        <g:each in="${sectionInstanceList}" status="j" var="sectionInstance">                   
        <li><g:link action="show" id="${sectionInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: sectionInstance, field: "name")}  </g:link></li>                    
        </g:each>               
    </ul>           
    </div>  
</g:each>
</header>
```

And in the Home controller I do this:-

```
def sectionService

    def index = 
    {
  List<Section> sectionList = sectionService.getSectionsForCurrentPage()
  return [sectionList:sectionList];
    }
```

In the index page I do this:

```
    <g:render template="/layouts/headernav" />
```

The Markup result I get is this:-

```
<header>
</header>
```

I'm still learning grails so It's probably something obvious , but why is the header not populated? There's a list containing Section objects and I think I'm referencing the list correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had it a lot of it wrong. However working through it and getting running has helped me learn more about groovy and grails. Thanks for formatting my question Kelly.